# Reverse the d3-hierarchy (d3-tree) graph to left side to show downstream as well

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two sets of data one for upstream and one for downstream. Both upstream and downstream have same master node of John.

**Upstream data**

```
var upstreamData = [
  { name: "John", parent: "" },
  { name: "Ann", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Adam", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Chris", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Tina", parent: "Ann" },
  { name: "Sam", parent: "Ann" },
  { name: "Rock", parent: "Chris" },
  { name: "will", parent: "Chris" },
  { name: "Nathan", parent: "Adam" },
  { name: "Roger", parent: "Tina" },
  { name: "Dena", parent: "Tina" },
  { name: "Jim", parent: "Dena" },
  { name: "Liza", parent: "Nathan" }
];
```

**Downstream data**

```
var downstreamData = [
  { name: "John", parent: "" },
  { name: "Kat", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Amily", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Summer", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Loki", parent: "Kat" },
  { name: "Liam", parent: "Kat" },
  { name: "Tom", parent: "Amily" }
];
```

I am able to represent upstream data to the right side of the master node using d3 hierarchy and d3 tree, below is the image

[image]

How do I represent downstream data to left side of master node John, so that I can see both upstream and downstream data of john at once in same graph?

Below is the link to my codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-practice-forked-y69kkw?file=/src/index.js

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've adapted my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569616/how-to-create-a-bowtie-method-diagram-in-d3-js/65578840#65578840) so it suits your data structure.

This method has key steps:

0. *Remember that for a horizontal layout you flip `x` and `y`...*
1. Compute both tree layouts for upstream and downstream
2. Make the root nodes have the same `x` and `y`
3. Re-compute the `y` coordinate for every node such that the root is in the center and the downsteam branches work leftward and the upstream branches work right-ward.
4. Draw both trees

If you skip step 3 then you end up with this (where red is upstream and green is downstream):

[image]

So to flip this around so that the downstream tree is in the left-hand side and the upstream tree is on the right-hand side (and the root is centered) :

- We need to halve the `y` coordinate (which is it's `x`) of the upstream node and add half of the `innerWidth`. For the root this puts in the centre, but for the descendants it puts them proportionally on the right hand side:

```
Array.from(nodesUpstream).forEach(n => n.y = (n.y * 0.5) + innerWidth / 2);
```

Then, do the same halving of the downstream node `y` coordinates (which are `x` really...) but `*-1` which 'mirrors' them and then add `innerWidth / 2` back. The root will still be in the centre, but now the descendants are proportionally on the left hand side and mirrored

```
Array.from(nodesDownstream).forEach(n => n.y = ((n.y * 0.5) * -1) + innerWidth / 2);
```

See the working snippet below with your OP data:

```js
const nodeRadius = 6;
const width = 600; 
const height = 400; 
const margin = { top: 24, right: 24, bottom: 24, left: 24 };
const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

const rootName = "John";

const treeLayout = d3.tree().size([innerHeight, innerWidth]);

const stratified = d3.stratify()
  .id(function (d) { return d.name; })
  .parentId(function (d) { return d.parent; });
  
const linkPathGenerator = d3.linkHorizontal()
  .x((d) => d.y)
  .y((d) => d.x);
  
// create 2x trees 
const nodesUpstream = treeLayout(d3.hierarchy(stratified(upstreamData)).data);
const nodesDownstream = treeLayout(d3.hierarchy(stratified(downstreamData)).data);

// align the root node x and y
const nodesUpRoot = Array.from(nodesUpstream).find(n => n.data.name == rootName);
const nodesDownRoot = Array.from(nodesDownstream).find(n => n.data.name == rootName);
nodesDownRoot.x = nodesUpRoot.x;
nodesDownRoot.y = nodesUpRoot.y;

// NOTE - COMMENT OUT THIS STEP TO SEE THE INTEMEDIARY STEP
// for horizontal layout, flip x and y...
// right hand side (upstream): halve and add width / 2 to all y's (which are for x)
Array.from(nodesUpstream).forEach(n => n.y = (n.y / 2) + innerWidth / 2);
// left hand side (downstream): halve and negate all y's (which are for x) and add width / 2
Array.from(nodesDownstream).forEach(n => n.y = ((n.y / 2) * -1) + innerWidth / 2);

// render both trees
// index allows left hand and right hand side to separately selected and styled
[nodesUpstream, nodesDownstream].forEach(function(nodes, index) {

  // adds the links between the nodes
  // need to select links based on index to prevent bad rendering
  svg.selectAll(`links-${index}`)
    .data(nodes.links())
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", `link links-${index}`)
    .attr("d", linkPathGenerator);

  // adds each node as a group
  // need to select nodes based on index to prevent bad rendering
  var nodes = svg.selectAll(`.nodes-${index}`)
    .data(nodes.descendants())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", `node nodes-${index}`) 
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
      // x and y flipped here to achieve horizontal placement
      return `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`;
    });

  // adds the circle to the node
  nodes.append("circle")
    .attr("r", nodeRadius);

  // adds the text to the node
  nodes.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("y", -20)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

});
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* upstream */
path.links-0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ff0000;
}

/* downstream */
path.links-1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #00ff00;
}

text {
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 3px white, -1px 1px 3px white, 1px -1px 3px white,
    1px 1px 3px white;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
}

circle {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Upstream data
var upstreamData = [
  { name: "John", parent: "" },
  { name: "Ann", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Adam", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Chris", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Tina", parent: "Ann" },
  { name: "Sam", parent: "Ann" },
  { name: "Rock", parent: "Chris" },
  { name: "will", parent: "Chris" },
  { name: "Nathan", parent: "Adam" },
  { name: "Roger", parent: "Tina" },
  { name: "Dena", parent: "Tina" },
  { name: "Jim", parent: "Dena" },
  { name: "Liza", parent: "Nathan" }
];
// Downstream data

var downstreamData = [
  { name: "John", parent: "" },
  { name: "Kat", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Amily", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Summer", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Loki", parent: "Kat" },
  { name: "Liam", parent: "Kat" },
  { name: "Tom", parent: "Amily" }
];
</script>
```

Which results in:
[image]

There's 2 limitations: the root is drawn twice (you could skip labelling John for one of them I guess) and more importantly, the depth of the trees is not taken into account when re-laying-out the `y` coordinates. If you had a deeper upstream tree you would see this because it would still be laid out on the right hand half and be much more 'scrunched'.

### Edit

To fix node widths (according to depth) then you can use this:

```
const depthFactor = 60;
Array.from(nodesUpstream).forEach(n => n.y = (n.depth * depthFactor) + innerWidth / 2);
Array.from(nodesDownstream).forEach(n => n.y = (innerWidth / 2) - (n.depth * depthFactor));
```

Example:

```js
const nodeRadius = 6;
const width = 600; 
const height = 400; 
const margin = { top: 24, right: 24, bottom: 24, left: 24 };
const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

const rootName = "John";

const treeLayout = d3.tree().size([innerHeight, innerWidth]);

const stratified = d3.stratify()
  .id(function (d) { return d.name; })
  .parentId(function (d) { return d.parent; });
  
const linkPathGenerator = d3.linkHorizontal()
  .x((d) => d.y)
  .y((d) => d.x);
  
// create 2x trees 
const nodesUpstream = treeLayout(d3.hierarchy(stratified(upstreamData)).data);
const nodesDownstream = treeLayout(d3.hierarchy(stratified(downstreamData)).data);

// align the root node x and y
const nodesUpRoot = Array.from(nodesUpstream).find(n => n.data.name == rootName);
const nodesDownRoot = Array.from(nodesDownstream).find(n => n.data.name == rootName);
nodesDownRoot.x = nodesUpRoot.x;
nodesDownRoot.y = nodesUpRoot.y;

// for horizontal layout, flip x and y...
const depthFactor = 60;
Array.from(nodesUpstream).forEach(n => n.y = (n.depth * depthFactor) + innerWidth / 2);
Array.from(nodesDownstream).forEach(n => n.y = (innerWidth / 2) - (n.depth * depthFactor));

// render both trees
// index allows left hand and right hand side to separately selected and styled
[nodesUpstream, nodesDownstream].forEach(function(nodes, index) {

  // adds the links between the nodes
  // need to select links based on index to prevent bad rendering
  svg.selectAll(`links-${index}`)
    .data(nodes.links())
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", `link links-${index}`)
    .attr("d", linkPathGenerator);

  // adds each node as a group
  // need to select nodes based on index to prevent bad rendering
  var nodes = svg.selectAll(`.nodes-${index}`)
    .data(nodes.descendants())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", `node nodes-${index}`) 
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
      // x and y flipped here to achieve horizontal placement
      return `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`;
    });

  // adds the circle to the node
  nodes.append("circle")
    .attr("r", nodeRadius);

  // adds the text to the node
  nodes.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("y", -20)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

});
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* upstream */
path.links-0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ff0000;
}

/* downstream */
path.links-1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #00ff00;
}

text {
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 3px white, -1px 1px 3px white, 1px -1px 3px white,
    1px 1px 3px white;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
}

circle {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Upstream data
var upstreamData = [
  { name: "John", parent: "" },
  { name: "Ann", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Adam", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Chris", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Tina", parent: "Ann" },
  { name: "Sam", parent: "Ann" },
  { name: "Rock", parent: "Chris" },
  { name: "will", parent: "Chris" },
  { name: "Nathan", parent: "Adam" },
  { name: "Roger", parent: "Tina" },
  { name: "Dena", parent: "Tina" },
  { name: "Jim", parent: "Dena" },
  { name: "Liza", parent: "Nathan" }
];
// Downstream data

var downstreamData = [
  { name: "John", parent: "" },
  { name: "Kat", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Amily", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Summer", parent: "John" },
  { name: "Loki", parent: "Kat" },
  { name: "Liam", parent: "Kat" },
  { name: "Tom", parent: "Amily" }
];
</script>
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is what i need. Could please help me out, how do i give fix node length for all nodes. tried doing changing `Array.from(nodesUpstream).forEach(n => n.y = (n.y * 0.5) + innerWidth / 2);`  and also tried `nodes.forEach(function (d) {     d.y = d.depth * 180;   }); ` but isn't giving the desired result.

Comment: @young_minds1 - see my edit

Comment: Thank you. it was such easy fix for you. but was not able to do it on my own.will have to learn d3.